# Fast R CNN Toy example can not find A2_RunWithPyModel.py file on CNTK

Tags: cntk

I'm trying to run the toy example and able to run step 1: Run A1_GenerateInputROIs.py, but not step 2:Run A2_RunWithPyModel.py.

The directory: "C:\Users\leetr\Downloads\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN" dose not contain the file "A2_RunWithPyModel.py".

There got to be something simple that I missed. However, I could not find the issue after spend fair amount of time on it.

CNTK version is  CNTK-2-0rc2-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only and the Python version is 3.5. I following the installation instruction on https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN#example-data-and-baseline-model.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a very recent change. We added tests for the Fast R-CNN example and renamed the A2 scripts in the process. This will be reflected in RC3. In your version the script should be called something like A2_RunCntk_py.py (look for A2_*_py.py). [P. Kranen, MSFT]

Comment: pkranen, Thank you very much for your helps. I did ran into other issues after runing the A2_RunCnk_PY.PY. I will try the RC3 version later.